# The metric spaces are Tychonoff spaces

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from "Elementos de Topología general" by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias.

> Since the sum and the product of real continous functions, defined in any topological space, are continuous we can easily prove that *every metric space is a Tychonoff spaces*. So we suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space and we consider a closed set $F$ a point $p\notin F$ and so we define a function $f:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ by the condiction 
>   $$
> f(x)=\frac{d(x,p)}{d(x,p)+d(x,F)}
> $$
>   where $d(x,F):=\mathscr{inf}\{d(x,a):a\in F\}$. So we observe that $f(p)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for any $x\in F$; then $f$ is continuous, since any function $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as 
>   $$
> g(x)=d(x,A)
> $$
>
> for any $x\in X$ and for any fixed $A\subseteq X$, is a countinuous function and so $f$ is continuous  function, since the sum and the ratio of continuous function is a continuous function.
>
> Well by definition of Tychonoff space we can claim that the metric space $(X,d)$ is a Tychonoff space.

Well unfortunately I don't be able to prove that the function $g$ is continuous: could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only $g$ is continuous, $g$ is, in fact, non-expansive:
$$|g(x) - g(y)| \le d(x, y),$$
for all $x, y$. To prove this, suppose $x, y \in X$ and $a \in A$. Then, by triangle inequality,
$$d(x, a) \le d(x, y) + d(y, a).$$
By definition of $d(x, A)$, we have $d(x, A) \le d(x, a)$, so,
$$d(x, A) \le d(x, y) + d(y, a)$$
for all $x, y \in X$ and $a \in A$. Because this holds for all $a \in A$, we therefore see that $d(x, A) - d(x, y)$ is a lower bound for $d(y, a)$ when $a \in A$. So, the infimum must be larger than this lower bound, i.e.
$$d(x, A) - d(x, y) \le \inf_{a \in A} d(y, a) = d(y, A).$$
Thus, $d(x, A) - d(y, A) \le d(x, y)$. Symmetrically, $d(y, A) - d(x, A) \le d(y, x) = d(x, y)$, hence
$$|d(x, A) - d(y, A)| \le d(x, y),$$
as promised.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why if $|g(x)-g(y)|\le d(x,y)$ then g is continuous? Could you explain better, please?

Comment: For the first question, recall that $|a| = \max\{a, -a\}$, so $|a| \le b$ if and only if $a \le b$ and $-a \le b$. That's what I'm doing here, with $b = d(x, y)$ and $a = d(x, A) - d(y, A)$. For the second question, fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta = \varepsilon$. To show $g$ is continuous at $y$, then observe $$d(x, y) < \delta \implies |g(x) - g(y)| \le d(x, y) < \delta = \varepsilon,$$ proving continuity at $y$ (which is also uniform continuity!).

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro We can take $\delta=\varepsilon$ at any point!

Comment: @user754697 So to prove the continuity of $g$ I must prove that for every neighborhood $U_{g(x)}$ of $g(x)$ there exist a neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $g(V_x)\subseteq U_{g(x)}$: so in your proof the neighborhood of $x$ is the ball $B(x,\delta)$ but I don't understand what is the neighborhood of $g(x)$. Could you explain to me this?

Comment: For any neighbourhood  $U_{g(x)}$, by definition of the topology induced by a metric, there must exist an open ball $B(g(x), \varepsilon) \subseteq U_{g(x)}$. Then, $B(x; \varepsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, and $g(B(x; \varepsilon)) \subseteq B(g(x), \varepsilon) \subseteq U_{g(x)}$. Note that if $y \in B(x; \varepsilon)$, then $d(x, y) < \varepsilon$, so $|g(y) - g(x)| < \varepsilon$, and so $g(y) \in B(g(x); \varepsilon)$.